# The fastest way to stream audio with java server

Tags: java, udp, webrtc, audio-streaming

I want to develop a audio streaming server in java with human voice.
I would like to know if someone has already test the some technologies as httpserver (icecast, httpservlet as jetty) , rtspserver or webrtc.
 I need something faster. 
I think also to send stream with simple UDP and add some informations for client. 
As audio format i think i'll use opus because it is optimized for human voice. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i checked some technologies as Kurento but finally my choice is:
Encoding with opus
Sending stream to clients with UDP server

I would like to know if you ever worked for sending a stream with multiple thread. Because i dont know how i can share encoded stream between threads.
 Because i want to create
1 Thread who listens connections from client and saves ip+port
1 Thread who captures micro and encodes the stream 
1 Thread for each client for sending the encoded  stream